# No emulators are currently running in Android studio bumblebee. However, ADB shows the emulator in the device list

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

No emulators are currently running in Android studio bumblebee. However, ADB shows the emulator in the device list

[Not running but showing in the device list(ADB)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCvIE.png)

**EDIT**

When the running process is stopped from the task manager, it works
[[tasks-list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcWzK.png)]

Comment: Question needs some explanation

Comment: I face the same problem. The emulator starts well with an application launched. Then at some point, while playng with the app the emulator disappears with 'No emulators currently running' message in the Emulator pannel. But Android Studio shows that the app is still running and the emulator is listed in windows 10 task manager, and there are no errors in logcat.

Comment: Try this on your project root > local.properties file set this: sdk.dir=C:\\Users\\YOUR_USER_NAME\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk